# How to change date format in Altium schematic title block?

Tags: schematics, altium

[image]

This is the default title block. As you can see it already has a date filled in. But being european I don't like the mm-dd-yyy order. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: I think the only possible way to do this is make your own template, there you can adapt the data field.

Comment: I chose this way. And I see that in the new custom title block the date is formatted the way I want it. So probably according to regional settings from the OS.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's the original or a bespoke template, as soon as you edit the sch file the date will reformat to the current regional setting.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way from Altium Designer. Altium just uses the Regional settings in Windows to determine how to display  =CurrentDate in the title block. So, change it in Windows:

Start->Control Panel->Clock, Language and Region->Change the date, time, or number format

You may have to type the desired format in rather than just selecting from the drop-down box.

[image]